# Is there any way to display raw data of a .PHP file with using Java script in my localhost?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to display the raw contents of a .php file using javascript but i am unable to get it. The php file is in my localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is server code. JS is client code. (Execution talking)
You can't access your PHP files from your .js

The only thing you can do is to get some PHP output using Ajax but I think that is not what you are aiming for.

Comment: Thank you but i am hoping that there is way to do this question.

Comment: I understand what you are looking for. I'm pretty sure you can't do that though. JS is run in the browser locally and the only way you can access a PHP file in the server is Ajax. If you want to try anyways you can see XMLHttpRequest() docs. Another thing you can do is to have a function (in your PHP file) that prints itself as a string (using file() or file_get_contents() for example), now from JS you can retrieve the output  using Ajax. You have to add some PHP code. Maybe this brings you a little bit closer to what you want ;)

Comment: Both php and html files are local files. Is there any way to access contents of a local .php like extracting data from .txt file with javascript.

Comment: You can use FileReader to read local files but these MUST be selected by the user. As far as I know **you can't open files in local drive from JS** looking for them or looping through folders. So short answer: no

Answer (score 0):

You can use `show_source()` function to output the file with the PHP syntax:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
 show_source("test.php"); 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This function has to parameter `show_source(filename,return)`. filename is required and second parameter is optional if this parameter is set to TRUE, this function will return the highlighted code as a string, instead of printing it out. Default is FALSE

Comment: I need a java script code to display contents of php.

Comment: PHP code interpret in server and output of php code send to client. and javascript has not access to php files in server.

Comment: I understood what you are saying. I am looking a script which display contents of my local .php files. All files are in local. There is no server required to access html pages. I was searched in the web for this question, so many of them are displaying contents of .php file with java script by using html uploading. The raw data was displayed when a .php file upload to the form. If you know anything about it, please inform to me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use client side code to cause the server to provide the server side source code.

You would need to work on the server to create a URL which provided the data you want.

You could then fetch it using a link, JavaScript's XMLHttpRequest or whatever other method took your fancy.